# Python: Extract all characters between a two groups of characters in a string

Tags: python, string, extract

Say I have a list of strings corresponding to a file name:

```
files = ['variable_timestep_model321_experiment123.csv',
      'variable_timestep_model2_experiment21.csv',
      'variable_timestep_model4321_experimentname1234.csv',
      'variable_timestep_model0_experiment0.csv']
```

Where each file name has the format:
`'variable_timestemp_modelname_experimentname.csv'`

In this filename `variable` and `timestemp` are not changing, however the `modelname` and `experimentname` are. I want to extract the model name, so the expected output would be:

```
['model321',
 'model2',
 'model4321',
 'model0']
```

Because I know `variable_timestemp_` stays the same, is there an easy way to extract X amount of characters between `variable_timestep_` on the left and `_` on the right?

Comment: Why have you tagged this regex? Do you need a regex-based solution? For that matter, why have you tagged it list? Do you not know how to iterate over the list of files, or do you think something about the list is otherwise relevant to the problem?

Comment: Both valid statements. And yes I do know how to iterate over a list of files..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way:

```
models = [name.split('_')[2] for name in files]
```

Comment: Nice! I need to learn some more string methods. There's probably a lot of others I could/should be using to manipulate them.